# Об определении переменной

Tags: python, numpy

Код:

```
def vectorize_sequences(word_index, dimension=10000):
  results = np.zeros((len(word_index), dimension))
for i, sequence in enumerate(word_index):
  results [i, sequence] = 1
return results
x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data) 
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
```

на вторую переменную `results` ошибка, что она не определена. Дык а вроде бы два раза определена, нет? спасибо

Comment: Про отступы не забыли?

Comment: да нет вроде, да и на отступы своя ошибка, нет?

Comment: в обновлённой версии цикл ФОР на одном уровне с переменной функции, переменная в цикле со своим отступом, но машина всё равно считает, что переменная не определена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот так?

```
def vectorize_sequences(word_index, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(word_index), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(word_index):
        results [i, sequence] = 1
    return results
```

Comment: ларчик просто открывался: один селезень забыл импортировать np..